# How to set a logarithmic mouse acceleration in Linux?

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 for gaming and Xubuntu for work. My problem is that having to switch between OS daily screws up both my gaming performance and work performance since I have to constantly re-adjust myself to different mouse accelerations.

I found that setting a 2.8x acceleration and 8px threshold in Linux mitigated a lot this issue, but I still can't wrap my head around why would Linux use a fixed mouse acceleration instead of a natural one. It feels so... Unnatural. Pun intended.

So, my question is : How do I set a logarithmic mouse acceleration (or one that imitates Windows 10's one the best) in Linux?